# Swift 3 - FBSDKGraphRequest - Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

I am requesting Facebook login and get 4 **"Type 'Any' has no subscript members"** issues in the following lines:

```
PFUser.current()?["name"] = result["name"]
PFUser.current()?["email"] = result["email"]
PFUser.current()?["gender"] = result["gender"]

let userId = result["id"] as! String
```

This is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, gender, email"])

        graphRequest.start { (connection, object, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error while making Graph request to Facebook")
            } else {
                if let result = object {

                    PFUser.current()?["name"] = result["name"]
                    PFUser.current()?["email"] = result["email"]
                    PFUser.current()?["gender"] = result["gender"]

                    PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()

                    let userId = result["id"] as! String
                    self.saveUserImageInBackground(userId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The app won't launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
override func viewDidLoad() {


        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, gender, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection,  result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){

                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]


                     PFUser.current()?["name"]= data["first_name"] as? NSString
                    PFUser.current()?["email"] = data["email"] as? NSString

                  }
```